# I have problem with form of partial fractions

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

here is my problem:

1.for example why the form of this partial fraction should be this? 
$$\frac{{4{x^2}}}{{\left( {x - 1} \right){{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{A}{{x - 1}} + \frac{B}{{x - 2}} + \frac{C}{{{{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}}}$$

What is wrong with $$\frac{{4{x^2}}}{{\left( {x - 1} \right){{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{A}{{x - 1}} + \frac{B}{{{{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}}}$$

2.Here:
$$\frac{{8{x^2} - 12}}{{x\left( {{x^2} + 2x - 6} \right)}} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{{Bx + C}}{{{x^2} + 2x - 6}}$$

what is wrong with $$\frac{{8{x^2} - 12}}{{x\left( {{x^2} + 2x - 6} \right)}} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{{B}}{{{x^2} + 2x - 6}}$$

I mean I dont understand why the form of Partial fraction should be like this image below and what is wrong with my examples?

[image]

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure). If you have a root of higher order then you have to include all lower orders as well in the decomposition

Answer (score 1):

As was said in comment higher just check Wikipedia.
And about your example, just try to write the system for coefficients $A$ and $B$ in the case 2. You will get that $A = 8$, because the coiffecent at $x^2$ equales 8, consueqently,  $-6*A = -48,$ not $-12$. It means that you can't rewrite $\frac{{8{x^2} - 12}}{{x\left( {{x^2} + 2x - 6} \right)}}$ as $ \frac{A}{x} + \frac{{B}}{{{x^2} + 2x - 6}}$